# Python: Calculate average for each hour in CSV?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, average, hour

I want to calculate the average for each hours using a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file:

Below is my DATA SET:

```
Timestamp    Temperature
9/1/2016 0:00:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:00:38    53.8
9/1/2016 0:01:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:01:38    53.8
9/1/2016 0:02:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:02:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:03:08    54.1
9/1/2016 0:03:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:04:38    54
9/1/2016 0:05:38    54
9/1/2016 0:06:08    54
9/1/2016 0:06:38    54
9/1/2016 0:07:08    54
9/1/2016 0:07:38    54
9/1/2016 0:08:08    54.1
9/1/2016 0:08:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:09:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:10:32    54
9/1/2016 0:11:02    54
9/1/2016 0:11:32    54
9/1/2016 0:00:08    54
9/2/2016 0:00:20    32
9/2/2016 0:00:50    32
9/2/2016 0:01:20    32
9/2/2016 0:01:50    32
9/2/2016 0:02:20    32
9/2/2016 0:02:50    32
9/2/2016 0:03:20    32
9/2/2016 0:03:50    32
9/2/2016 0:04:20    32
9/2/2016 0:04:50    32
9/2/2016 0:05:20    32
9/2/2016 0:05:50    32
9/2/2016 0:06:20    32
9/2/2016 0:06:50    32
9/2/2016 0:07:20    32
9/2/2016 0:07:50    32
```

Here is my code for calculating per day average, but I want per hour:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas
def same_day(date_string): # Remove year
return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%S").strftime(%m%d')

df = pandas.read_csv('/home/kk/Desktop/cal_Avg.csv',index_col=0,usecols=[0, 1], names=['Timestamp', 'Discharge'],converters={'Timestamp': same_day})

print(df.groupby(level=0).mean())
```

My desired output is like:

```
Timestamp              Temp          *        Avg
9/1/2016 0:00:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:00:38    53.8    ?avg for this hour
9/1/2016 0:01:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:01:38    53.8    ?avg for this hour
9/1/2016 0:02:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:02:38    54.1
```

Now I want the average for specific hours , Min

Desired output:

Here I am printing only 5 hours output for date 01-09-2016 and 02-09-16

```
010900              54.362727         45.497273
010901              54.723276         45.068103
010902              54.746847         45.370270
010903              54.833913         44.931304
010904              54.971053         44.835088
010905              55.519444         44.459259
020901              31.742553         55.640426
020902              31.495556         55.655556
020903              31.304348         55.442609
020904              31.200000         55.437273
020905              31.294382         55.442697
```

Specific date and there specific hours?
How do I archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `index_col=[0]` for read first column to `index` and `parse_dates=[0]` for parse first column to `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0],, usecols=[0,1])
print (df)
                     Temperature
Timestamp                       
2016-09-01 00:00:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:00:38         53.8
2016-09-01 00:01:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:01:38         53.8
2016-09-01 00:02:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:02:38         54.1
2016-09-01 00:03:08         54.1
...
...
```

Then use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `hours` and aggregate [`Resampler.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.mean.html), but get `NaN` for missing data in `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (df.resample('H').mean())
                     Temperature
Timestamp                       
2016-09-01 00:00:00    53.980952
2016-09-01 01:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 02:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 03:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 04:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 05:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 06:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 07:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 08:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 09:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 10:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 11:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 12:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 13:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 14:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 15:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 16:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 17:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 18:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 19:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 20:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 21:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 22:00:00          NaN
2016-09-01 23:00:00          NaN
2016-09-02 00:00:00    32.000000
```

Another solution is remove `minutes` and `seconds` by casting to `hours` and `groupby` by this `array`:

```
print (df.index.values.astype('<M8[h]'))
['2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00'
 '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00'
 '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00'
 '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00'
 '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-01T00'
 '2016-09-01T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00'
 '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00'
 '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00'
 '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00' '2016-09-02T00'
 '2016-09-02T00']

print (df.groupby([df.index.values.astype('<M8[h]')]).mean())
            Temperature
2016-09-01    53.980952
2016-09-02    32.000000
```

Also if need meean by months, days and hours is posible `groupby` by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
print (df.index.strftime('%m%d%H'))
['090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100'
 '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100'
 '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090100' '090200' '090200' '090200'
 '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200'
 '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200' '090200']

print (df.groupby([df.index.strftime('%m%d%H')]).mean())
        Temperature
090100    53.980952
090200    32.000000
```

Or if need mean only by hours `groupby` by [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html):

```
print (df.index.hour)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

print (df.groupby([df.index.hour]).mean())
   Temperature
0    44.475676
```

Comment: its calculating Average for per day ..i want for per hours?

Comment: Sorry, it is for me a bit unclear. I try add multiple solution, if is missing what you need, what is desired output from your input?

Comment: i want to calculate average for per hours like ;
for this hour want Average: 
2016-09-01 00:00:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:00:38         53.8
for this hour want Average: 
2016-09-01 00:02:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:02:38         54.1

like this...

Comment: Sorry, still unclear for me - you need groupby by `0` hour in all sample? Od by `month`, `day` and `hour` ?

Comment: I think the best is use small sample of data like `df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [1,2,3,4,5]}, index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24 15:08:04'), periods=5, freq='13H'))`

Comment: What is desired outpuf from my small sample?

Comment: each hours average i want..
for this hour this is the Avg ,for next Hour this is the AVG

Comment: Yes, what is output of my sample input? `df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [1,2,3,4,5]}, index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24 15:08:04'), periods=5, freq='13H'))` ?

Comment: in your input one one time is there,,for 24-02-2015 15:08:04,if u give more time then u can get AVG,like if u give  2015-02-24 15:10:05
now we want to calculate this two time and give AVG for it.

Comment: Ant this is wrong output? `print (df.groupby([df.index.values.astype('<M8[h]')]).mean())`

Comment: this is giving correct output but for date 01-09-2016 but in this date so many hours are there i want per hour separately.See my desire output i edit my question..

Comment: Sorry, still unclear. If use `9/1/2016 1:20:38` then there is `1` hour ? Or there are multiple same times like `9/1/2016 0:00:38    53.8, 9/1/2016 0:00:38    53.8` and need mean of duplicate dates?

Comment: will separate  the data and than according to time can we calculate per hour Avg?? is it possible?

Comment: yes i want per hours so if there is a 9/1/2016 0:00:38 53.8, 9/1/2016 0:00:38 53.8.
so here we will calculate as 12am to 1am then 1am to 2 am like that

Comment: So you need `print (df.resample('H').mean())` ?

Comment: yes but this is also giving output like this only:(not separately ) 
2016-09-01  53.99
2016-09-02  32.00

Comment: What mens separately? It means there are `NaN` ? Sorry, I want help you, but I need sample and desired output from sample.  Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and I try help you. But I still dont know what do you want exactly :(

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..its working now..
here is one more question can we calculate this for multiple columns?
like temperature is there,one more temp2,temp3...so on

Comment: Do you use resample solution?

Comment: I check my all solutions and I think it can works witjh multiple columns - If need mean in all columns also.

Comment: yes i use Resample solution ..Okay i ll check with the multiple columns.
i can export my result in some other csv ?

Comment: Yes, use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Yes, I think you need `df.reset_index().to_csv('myfile.csv')`

Comment: and what about if i give i want to see only for 5 hours than how can we do?

Comment: I think you need `DatatimeIndex` (print df.index) and then use http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing

Comment: Sure, but I dont know exactly what you think - resample by `5 hours` or group data by `5 hour` and aggreagate mean or select data from `2016-09-01 01:00:00 to 2016-09-01 06:00:00`. Maybe the best is create new question. Small advice - check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) it is really good advice. Thanks.

Comment: thanks..actually i want to give manually if i want for 10 hrs 5 hrs,,or 5 min like that ..

Comment: and how can i export my result in a json array format?

Comment: check - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-writer and [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: try `df.to_json('myfile.json')`

Comment: ValueError: No columns to parse from file
this error is coimg

Comment: Try `df.reset_index().to_json('myfile.json')`

Comment: What is `df.info()` ?

Comment: No. I am not get it.

Comment: rng = date_range('2016-09-01', periods=5, freq='H')
i am using this but where should i mention data_range??

Comment: IIUC try `df.loc[rng]`

Comment: There is problem I have no your data. Selecting depends on many things, so it is imposible help you. Unfortunately.

Comment: same as my question ..according to my dataset which i given above..
like that only; IF i give 9/1/2016 this date and want to see only 5 hrs data AVG or 10 min data AVg ...like that

Comment: hmmm, maybe need `print (df.resample('5H').mean())` or `print (df.resample('10t').mean())`

Comment: its giving 5 hours AVG but its giving like combined all dates and than calculate avg..I want to calculate for this day give me only 5H avg..per hours individually

Comment: Unfortunately I dont understand without sample and desired output.

Comment: Yes, now it is more clear. So use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - `mask = pd.Series((df.index.minute < 6) & (df.index.hour < 6), index=df.index)` and then `print (df[mask])` - it filter dates less as 6 hour and less as 6 minutes.

Comment: hours are coming properly but by minute its not coming properly
  suppose,
whatever minutes are less than 1 min its coming like 01:00:23 like that...
i want only less than 1 min its taking hours also..

Comment: Hmmm, you need only from `01:01:23` to `01:05:23` minutes? `01:00:23` is `Hours:Minutes:Seconds` Then use `mask = pd.Series((df.index.minute.isin([1,2,3,4,5]) ) , index=df.index)`

Comment: It was untested, sorry. Use `mask = pd.Series(df.index.minute, index=df.index).isin([1,2,3,4,5])`

Comment: still hours are also coming

Comment: So need this `mask = pd.Series(df.index.minute, index=df.index).isin([1,2,3,4,5]) & pd.Series((df.index.hour < 6), index=df.index)` ?

Comment: And actually what it is printing i want for 5 hours what is the average..like that for 10 min what is the average...Its giving separately ..
actually i want for 5 hours the is the Average..
for 10 min this is the average...

Comment: I dont understand.

Comment: Sorry, Neha B - I am one idea - you can send me email (in my profile) with your sample data and desired output. Then can help you. I still dont understand what you need. thank you.

Comment: see;
if i say its coming less then 2 min data..So it is coming separately for 01:08 min its giving avg, BUT i want less then 2 min this is the AVG for 1 parameter and this is for 2nd parameter accordind to date
2016-09-01 00:01:08                   53.8              45.8
2016-09-01 00:01:38                   53.8              45.8
2016-09-01 00:02:08                   53.8              45.8
2016-09-01 00:02:38                   54.1              45.8

Comment: for 01-09-2016 what is the Avg for 10 min,,,for 02-09-2016 what is the Avg for 10 min like that

Comment: what is your mail id so its helpful for me .

Answer (score 0):

I would first define a new column `hour` for readability, then `groupBy` it

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('/home/kk/Desktop/cal_Avg.csv',index_col=None)
df['hour']=df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda s:s[:-3])
df[['hour','Temprature']].groupBy('hour').mean()
```

Comment: how to find missing timestamp..i want to find missing data ..my data is in every 30 second data and if some data is missing..how to find those data?